# Rust `unresolved import` on third party library

Tags: import, module, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I want to compile a simple rust program using a third party library named warp:

```
[package]
name = "hello-world-warp"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
warp = "0.1.18"
```

In `src/main.rs`:

```rust
use warp::{self, path, Filter};

fn main() {
    // GET /hello/warp => 200 OK with body "Hello, warp!"
    let hello = warp::path!("hello" / String)
        .map(|name| format!("Hello, {}!", name));

    warp::serve(hello)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030));
}
```

When I run `cargo build` I see it download warp and lots of transitive dependencies, then I get the errors:

```
Compiling hello-world-warp v0.1.0 (<path>) error[E0432]: unresolved import `warp`
 --> src/main.rs:3:12
  |
3 | use warp::{self, path, Filter};
  |            ^^^^ no `warp` in the root

error: cannot find macro `path!` in this scope
```

I've gone through various docs on modules and crates. What am I doing wrong in this simple scenario?

Comment: What happens if you remove `self`? Note that it's not really needed anyways, since it's already in scope (at least in Rust 2018).

Comment: If you don't want to specify `extern crate` you need to use the 2018 edition and add `edition = "2018"` to your `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've accidentally set your Cargo project to backwards-compatible mode that emulates an old "2015" version of the language.

To be able to use normal Rust syntax, add:

```
edition = "2021"
```

to your `Cargo.toml`'s `[package]` section.

When starting new projects, always use `cargo new`. It will ensure the latest edition flag is set correctly.

Comment: wow, that was it :) with no other changes, it worked! Thanks!